# why python join zombie processes when starting a new one?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

why when i create a process and i have `n` children in zombie state python join them?

```
In [1]: def quick_process():
...:     pass
...: 
In [2]: import multiprocessing
In [3]: import time
In [4]: for i in range(5):
...:     multiprocessing.Process(target=quick_process).start()
...:     time.sleep(1)
...:
In [5]: import os
In [6]: while True:
...:     try:
...:         pid, status = os.waitpid(-1, 0)
...:         print(pid, status)
...:     except ChildProcessError:
...:         break
...:     
5767 0
```

the `time.sleep(1)` statement is for making sure that the process is in zombie state when i loop again, nothing more. as you can see there's only one children left when the `while` executes. in this example `n = 1` but with a greater value it also occurs. why python does that? shouldn't i explicitly join those processes? can anybody tell me what's going on here?  thanks

Comment: why shouldn't multiprocessing waiting for children? This is a high level interface, and the user shouldn't be bothered with low level stuff.

Comment: I don't think your processes are zombies at all; on the contrary. For them to be zombies, replace the ``pass`` with something like ``while True: pass``.

Comment: because i need to do something with those children when i join them and by starting new processes i wouldn't notice when they finish

Comment: a process become a zombie when it finishes and its parent have not join him, so those processes are zombies

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't join the processes. The processes exit when `quick_process` is executed. You can still `join` the processes afterwards which will return immediately if the process already terminated. Example:

```
import multiprocessing

def quick_process():
    pass

processes = []
for _ in range(5):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=quick_process)
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)

for p in processes:
    p.join()  # returns when the process terminates
```